# how to make at least one field mandatory in contact form

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a contact form with 4 fields and only phone number field is mandatory. I would like to change it and make phone or email field as mandatory. One of them have to be filled out. If someone fill email field, then phone field is not mandatory any more and vice versa.

Below is a code I have to change.

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $.validator.addMethod(
        'regex',
        function (value, element, regexp) {
          var check = false
          return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value)
        },
        'Sprawdź swoje dane.'
      )
      var validator = $('#sfform').validate({
        debug: false,
        ignore: '.ignore',
        rules: {
          email: {
            required: false,
            email: true
          },
          mobile: {
            required: true,
            regex: /^((00|\+)[1-9]([\s-\.]?\d){6,11}|0?[1-9]([\s-\.]?\d){8})$/
          },
          '00N1t00000ADSD0': {
            required: true
          },
          hiddenRecaptcha: {
            required: function () {
              if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
                return true
              } else {
                return false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        messages: {
          email: {
            email: 'Błędny adres email'
          },
          mobile: {
            required: 'Numer telefonu jest wymagany',
            regex: 'Błędny numer telefonu'
          },
          '00N1t00000ADSD0':
            {
              required: 'Zgoda jest wymagana do uzyskania kontaktu'
            },
          hiddenRecaptcha: {
            required: 'Zanaczenie pola jest wymagane'
          }
        },
        submitHandler: function () {
          document.getElementById('sfform').submit()
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
          error.addClass('invalid-feedback')
          element.closest('.form-group').append(error)
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
          $(element).addClass('is-invalid')
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
          $(element).removeClass('is-invalid')
        }
      })
    })
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may return a boolean value depending on checking another field via:

```
rules: {
      email: {
        required: '#mobile:blank'
      },
      mobile: {
        required: '#email:blank',
        regex: /^((00|\+)[1-9]([\s-\.]?\d){6,11}|0?[1-9]([\s-\.]?\d){8})$/
      },
      ...
```

The above assumes that your fields have the IDs `#mobile` and `#email`.

Read more about "*dependency expression*" [here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/#required-dependency-expression) and about the different checks `:filled`, `:unchecked` or `:blank` [here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 0):

We already found solution

```
           rules: {
               email: {
                   required: function() {
                       if(document.getElementById('mobile').value == '') {
                           return true
                       } else {
                           return false
                       }
                   },
                   email: true,
               },
               mobile: {
                   required: function() {
                       if(document.getElementById('email').value == '') {
                           return true
                       } else {
                           return false
                       }
```